# Java SourceDataLine not calling update at end of first buffer

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

Shortened version of the question: Even though I've got it to work before, this code that tries to make some noise with javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine is not calling update after the first buffer is empty.

EDIT: Updated the code for 16-bit stereo.
The sound plays for the amount of samples definedwhen Output.open(format,buffersize) is called.

Distilled the code example to a two class project:

```
package javaxaudiotest;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaxAudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaxAudioDevice audio = new JavaxAudioDevice();
        audio.create();
        System.out.println("Hit enter to quit.");
        int c = 'a';
        while (c != '\n') {
            c = System.in.read();
        }

        audio.dispose();
    }

}
```

JavaxAudioDevice with libGDX and my own project specific stuff taken out.

```
package javaxaudiotest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class JavaxAudioDevice implements LineListener {

    byte[] byteBuf = null;

    boolean quit = false;
    boolean hasquit = false;
    boolean underflow = false;

    SourceDataLine Output;
    int leader = 1024;
    boolean notDoneYet = false;
    boolean alreadyLead = false;
    byte b = 0;


    public int create() {
        quit = false;
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
        try {
            Output = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create audio device. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return 1;
        }

        if (Output != null) {
            Output.addLineListener(this);
            try {
                Output.open(af,44100*8);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to open audio device. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return 2;
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Created JavaxAudioDevice");
        while (!Output.isOpen());
        update(null);
        System.err.println(Output.getFormat().toString());
        return 0;
    }


    public void dispose() {
        quit = true;
        Output.close();
        Output.flush();
        Output = null;
        hasquit = true;
    }

//LineListener
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent le) {
        if (le == null) System.err.println("Audio update");
        else System.err.println("Audio update " + le.toString());

        if ( !quit && ( le == null || le.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP ) ) {
            boolean uf = false;
            while (notDoneYet) {
                uf = true;
            }
            notDoneYet = true;
            if (uf) {
                underflow = true;
                System.err.println("underflow");
            }

            if (byteBuf == null) { //insert some leader tape
                short[] shortBuf = new short[44100*8];
                for (int i = 0; i < shortBuf.length; i+=2) {
                    shortBuf[i] = (short)((b++)*50);
                    shortBuf[i+1] = (short)((b++)*200);
                }

                byteBuf = new byte[shortBuf.length * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < byteBuf.length; ++i) {
                    //little endian
                    if (i % 2 == 0) byteBuf[i] = (byte) (shortBuf[i / 2]); //low byte
                    else byteBuf[i] = (byte) (shortBuf[i / 2] >> 8); //high byte
                }
            }
            Output.write(byteBuf, 0, byteBuf.length);
            Output.start();
            byteBuf = null;
            if (!Output.isRunning()) { //debug
                System.err.println("Output not running");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Output running");
            }

            short[] shortBuf = new short[44100*8];
            for (int i = 0; i < shortBuf.length; i+=2) {
                    if (i%2 == 0) shortBuf[i] = shortBuf[i+1] = (short)((b++)*100);
                    else shortBuf[i] = shortBuf[i+1] = (short)((b++)*150);
            }

            byteBuf = new byte[shortBuf.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < byteBuf.length; ++i) {
                //little endian\
                if (i % 2 == 0) byteBuf[i] = (byte) (shortBuf[i / 2]); //low byte
                else byteBuf[i] = (byte) (shortBuf[i / 2] >> 8); //high byte
            }

            notDoneYet = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
run:
Created JavaxAudioDevice
Audio update Open event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@4cac0ef5
Audio update
Output running
Audio update Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@4cac0ef5
Hit enter to quit.
PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian

Audio update Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@4cac0ef5
Audio update Close event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@4cac0ef5
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

EDIT: I replaced the "leader tape" with a copy of the sawtooth generating loop. I also initialized byteBuf to null so that it will activate that section. In addition I added a loop to wait until the line is open to force the first update. Now I get a fraction of a second of sawtooth wave in my ears. Still not updating automatically, though.

Original question below:

---

I'm using libGDX and I wrote some code to make some sound asynchronously to the main thread. Then I used libGDX's own AsyncExecutor for a couple threads and AudioDevice for audio. AudioDevice.write(short[],int,int) is blocking so I needed to execute that in another thread. It is successful. Unfortunately it sometimes stutters (always when run from netbeans). For instance when I run the gradle task :desktop:dist it makes a complete jar file and when run under Windows 10 it's clear as a bell.

So I'm making a desktop specific implementation of pcm output with javax.sound.sampled namely SourceDataLine. So I made a class that initiates sound and also acts as a listener for SourceDataLine. This class lives in the desktop subproject and is passed to the core subproject when the main class is created. It implements a small interface that's part of core. I have it set for 16-bit signed stereo pcm. I have a class in core that generates a square wave and returns an array of shorts.

Here's the problem: I don't hear anything and update (part of LineListener) isn't being called except for once at the beginning (start) and a couple times at the end (stop, close).

This is strange because I used SourceDataLine in a previous project as 8-bit signed mono pcm and that was successful. So I also tried to test the new version as 8-bit mono by only taking every other high byte from the short array. SourceDataLine only takes byte arrays.

```
public class JavaxAudioDevice implements AudioInterface, LineListener {

    // omitted stuff

    short[] curBuf;
    byte[] byteBuf;

    SourceDataLine Output;
    int leader = 1024; //leader "tape"

    @Override
    public int create() {
        quit = false;
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
//        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, false);
        try {
            Output = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create audio device. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return 1;
        }

        if (Output != null) {
            try {
                Output.open(af,leader);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to open audio device. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return 2;
            }
            Output.addLineListener(this);
        }
        System.err.println("Created JavaxAudioDevice");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[leader];
        alreadyLead = true;
        Output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        Output.start();
        System.err.println(Output.getFormat().toString());
        return 0;
    }

//omitted stuff

//LineListener
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent le) {
            if (le == null) System.err.println("Audio update");
            else System.err.println("Audio update " + le.toString());

        if ( !quit && ( le == null || le.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP ) ) {
            boolean uf = false;
            while (notDoneYet) {
                uf = true;
            }

            notDoneYet = true;
            if (uf) {
                underflow = true;
                System.err.println("underflow");
            }

            if (byteBuf == null) { //insert some leader tape
                byteBuf = new byte[leader];
                for (int i = 0; i < byteBuf.length; ++i)
                    byteBuf[i] = 0;

                if (alreadyLead) System.err.println("Using audio leader when not supposed to!");
                else alreadyLead = true;
            }
            Output.write(byteBuf, 0, byteBuf.length);
            Output.start();
            byteBuf = null;
            if (!Output.isRunning()) { //debug
                System.err.println("Output not running");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Output running");
            }

            aplay.call();
            curBuf = aplay.output;
            if (curBuf == null) {
                //I don't know how to help you
                notDoneYet = false;
                System.err.println("Unable to fill buffer");
                return;
            }
            byteBuf = new byte[curBuf.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < byteBuf.length; ++i) {
                //little endian
                if (i % 2 == 0) byteBuf[i] = (byte) (curBuf[i / 2]/*&255/**/); //low byte
                else byteBuf[i] = (byte) (curBuf[i / 2] >> 8); //high byte
            }

//            byteBuf = new byte[curBuf.length/2]; //debug 8 bit mono
//            for (int i = 0; i < byteBuf.length; ++i) {
//                byteBuf[i] = (byte) (curBuf[i*2] >> 8);
//            }

            notDoneYet = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Some sample output:

```
Created JavaxAudioDevice
Audio update Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@13ab2987
PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
Disposing
Audio update Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@13ab2987
Audio update Close event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@13ab2987
:desktop:run

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 33.128 secs
```

"Disposing" and below is after I exit the program. There should be several audio updates per second to refill the buffer.

At this point I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: this has a lot of problems - are you sure you did it  as you claim in the other version?

Comment: It's a bit more consolidated. The last one had a separate class to be the LineListener.

Comment: Conceptually it's the same: Define format, get line, open line, add listener, write buffer when it stops, restart. The main difference is the old version generated audio as part of the main loop whereas the version is to generate it independently. Just now I tried moving adding the listener before opening but it makes no difference other than also printing "Audio update Open..."    Anyways, what other problems do you see?

Comment: Made a new project with just two classes to isolate it from the massive gradle mess that is any libGDX project. It seems to play the first sawtooth buffer (a fraction of a second). It still isn't updating afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my answer. My previous experiment with javax.sound.sampled the main thread was involved with generating a buffer and restarting the sound when it detected it was done. In that experiment and what I was trying to do here was use LineListener like Mix_HookMusic() in SDL (an even older experiment).

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC60

When SDL_mixer runs out of buffer it calls the function you provide it to make more. This is not how LineListener works in java. It doesn't get called when it runs out of buffer.

Instead, treat it like it's own thread (it is). When you call SourceDataLine.start() it launches LineListener's event function in its own thread with the start event type and returns to the main thread. So when LineListener detects a start event it goes into a loop that makes a buffer and writes it to the device. SourceDataLine.write() returns when it has one or less buffer to go through. That gives the loop enough time to make another with a latency of exactly one buffer. SourceDataLine.stop() will launch another of LineListener's event function with the stop type. Now this second thread of the event function can set a boolean so the first knows it is time to quit and exit the loop.

Here's some example code that plays a tone for 5 seconds then is silent for another 5 before quitting.

EDIT: It seems writing at least one frame (what I call a sample) is important to make sure that the SourceDataLine.start() will work correctly. Since I'm using stereo 16-bit I need to device.write(new byte[4],0,4); at minimum before I call device.start();

JavaxAudioTest.java

```
package javaxaudiotest;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class JavaxAudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SourceDataLine device;
        int buffer = 44100/15; //buffer in bytes (4 per sample so 60 buffers per second)

        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
        try {
            device = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaxAudioTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return;
        }


        WaveGen wg = new WaveGen();
        JavaxAudioDevice jad = new JavaxAudioDevice();
        jad.gen = wg;
        jad.device = device;
        device.addLineListener(jad);

        try {
            device.open(af,buffer);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaxAudioTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return;
        }
        device.write(new byte[4], 0, 4); //absolutely essential
        device.start();

        System.out.println("Zzzzzzzzzz");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaxAudioTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzBWAH!");
        device.close();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaxAudioTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Baiyo");
        device.drain();
        device.close();
    }
}
```

JavaxAudioDevice.java

```
package javaxaudiotest;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class JavaxAudioDevice implements LineListener {
    boolean quit = false;
    byte[] byteBuf;
    int SampleRate = 44100;
    int buffer = SampleRate/60;
    public WaveGen gen;
    public SourceDataLine device;


    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.toString());
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            quit = true;
        }
        else if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.START) {
            while (!quit) {
                short[] buf = new short[buffer];
                for (int i=0; i<buf.length; ++i) {
                    buf[i] = gen.Output();
                }
                byteBuf = new byte[buf.length*4];
                for (int i=0; i<buf.length; ++i) {
                    byteBuf[i*4] = byteBuf[i*4+2] = (byte)buf[i];
                    byteBuf[i*4+1] = byteBuf[i*4+3] = (byte)(buf[i]>>8);
                }
                device.write(byteBuf, 0, byteBuf.length);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

WaveGen.java

```
package javaxaudiotest;

public class WaveGen {
    int Wave = 0;
    int Max = 1<<24;
    byte Fidelity = 20;
    int Level = 8;
    int Boost = 2000;
    int Stepper = (int)(110.0/44100*Max); //freq/44100*2^24

    short Output() {
        short ret = 0;
        Wave += Stepper;
        Wave %= Max;
        ret = (short)(( (Wave>>Fidelity)-Level )*Boost);
        return ret;
    }
}
```